# c# get parent from chlid instance

Tags: c#, class, reflection, types, instance

I try to get the parent Type of a instance. 
How can I do ?

Example :

```
public class a
{
     public b { get; set; }
}

public class b
{

}


var a = new a();
a.b = new b();

var parentType = a.b.??GetParentInstanceType()??
```

Comment: You're trying to get a's type from b?

Comment: Please be more clear with your names. May be find better names for `a` and `b`, and explain what you mean by *parent* and *child*.

Comment: I think it's not possible because instance of `b` doesn't hold any information about the `a` instance which referencing it

Comment: If you are using `a.b`, then wouldn't `a.GetType()` do what you want?

Comment: @JonB I was baffled by the same thing... Maybe there is some deeper problem not entirely clear from the question... O_o

Answer (score 6):

You can't.

You'd need to add a property to the child manually to keep track of the parent:

Here is one way:

```
public class A
{
    public B<A> Child { get; set; }
}

public class B<T>
{
    public T Parent { get; set; }
}

A a = new A();
a.Child = new B<A>();
a.Child.Parent = a;

Type parentType = a.Child.Parent.GetType();
```

Of course the problem here is that nothing stops you from forgetting to set `Parent` or setting the wrong `Parent`.