# C# Break down type parameter in generic method if its a nested class

Tags: c#, generics, nested

I am trying to pass a nested class into a generic method to evaluate all of its classes, for example

```
SharedClass.FindParentClass<GrandParent.Parent.Child>();
```

Generic Method:

```
public void FindParentClass<T>() where T: ISomeInterface, new()
{
  //Break down T to all of its classes
}
```

I want to avoid doing this:

```
SharedClass.FindParentClass<GrandParent,GrandParent.Parent,GrandParent.Parent.Child>();
```

Generic method that works for above code:

```
public void FindParent<TGrandParent, TParent, TChild>() where TGrandParent : IGrandParent, new()
                                                         where TParent : IParent, new()
                                                          where TChild : IChild, new()
{
 //all I have to do now is place the type parameters there where I want them    
}
```

I am not allowed to change the classes that have been used as type parameters, so every class inherits a different interface and has a public parameter-less constructor.

Comment: This isn't possible. Have a look at [c# get parent from chlid instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072077/c-sharp-get-parent-from-chlid-instance). You **can** determine the declaring object's _type_ using reflection: [.NET reflection - Get Declaring class type from instance property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017744/net-reflection-get-declaring-class-type-from-instance-property).

Comment: A generic is just a substitute for *one single* type, not a list of classes within a file. There is no generic constraint to get all nested classes within a parent-class. However this seems weird anyway. Why not simply let all your nested classes implement a commin interface and use this as constraint instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to work the way I intended it to, I had to write another (private) generic method that accepts all three type parameters:

```
private void PerformWith<GrandParent, Grandparent.Parent, GrandParent.Parent.Child>()
{
         //Perform something
}
```

So in my first generic method, I will use reflection to:

1. Determine all the parent types - with GetTypeInfo().ReflectedType
2. To get the new method, make it generic and invoke it.

It looks like this:

```
public void FindParentClass<T> where T: ISomeInterface, new()
{
   var parentClass = typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().ReflectedType;
   var grandparentClass = parentClass.GetTypeInfo().ReflectedType;

   var method = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.GetMethod("PerformWith", BindingFlags.NonPublic());
   var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { grandparentClass, parentClass, typeof(T) });
   genericMethod.Invoke(null, null);
}
```